# Javascript: How do i change the input?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I would like to update the contents of an input, with the Chrome console.

Class:

```
<input type="text" class="answerInput __web-inspector-hide-shortcut__" maxlength="20" autocomplete="off">
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] and take the [tour] to see how and what to ask. HINT: Post code and effort. What does "with the chrome console" mean?

Comment: @ParagBhayani What do you mean?

Comment: @Ras.M : I am not able to understand your question ,would you elaborate or explain more what do you need..

Comment: @ParagBhayani Normally, you will have to write an input yourself. But i will like to use a command in the Chrome console so it inputs "264."

Comment: @Ras.M Still I am not getting it, would try to explain it from the scratch

Comment: @ParagBhayani Lets say this is like a login section.

  User: ["Username"] <- I will like to put a input in here, from the console.

So lets say i putted in Bob.

  User: ["Bob"]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to type something like this into the console

For ID:

```
$('#ID-OF-INPUT-GOES-HERE').val('I will appear in input')
```

For Class:

```
$('.CLASS-OF-INPUT-GOES-HERE').val('I will appear in input')
```

or

```
document.getElementsByClassName('CLASS-OF-INPUT-GOES-HERE')[0].value = 'i will appear in input'
```

Comment: Yes, but can i seach by class?

Comment: @Ras.M Glad I could help